# How to change the TimeZone on Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, winapi

I'm creating a python program to change the timezone of my computer (permanently, or until it is changed again) on windows 10. The current program I currently have changes the time zone, but I am specifically trying to change the time zone to (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time and I'm having trouble understanding some of the parameters of the function im using (and changing the timezone to UTC)

I was unable to find the UTC timezone on this [Microsoft Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc749073(v=ws.10)) about TimeZones.

```
def changeTimeZone():
    win32api.SetTimeZoneInformation((-600, u'Coordinated Universal Time',
                                    (2000, 4, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0), 0,
                                     u'Coordinated Universal Time',
                                    (2000, 10, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), -60))
```

It changes the time, but I am unsure if it changes permanently, It also does not change the time to UTC. Checking the windows time zone says it appears to be switched to UTC, however when i manually set it to UTC instead of using the python program, the times are different.

Comment: I think Greenwich Standard Time (GMT) is the same thing as UTC.

Comment: You might want to refer to this more up to date [Microsoft Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones). Everything is relative to UTC, rather than GMT. (According to [this page](https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-gmt-and-utc/), there is a difference between the two, but it amounts to only fractions of a second.)

Comment: The windows gui, shows correctly that the timezone is Coordinated Universal Time, the problem is that the time is off, I think it has to do with the other parameters in the settimezoneinformation function, But I can't confirm that.

Comment: @BChiu You can set SYSTEMTIME to all zero to see if it helps: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: Setting all the fields to 0 appears to have worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing all paramters of the function to 0, adjusted the time to be the correct one.

```
def changeTimeZone():
    #win32api.SetTimeZoneInformation((-600, u'Coordinated Universal Time', (2000, 4, 1, 
#3, 0, 0, 0, 0), 0,
                                     #u'Coordinated Universal Time', (2000, 10, 1, 2, 
#0, 0, 0, 0), -60))

    win32api.SetTimeZoneInformation((0, u'Coordinated Universal Time', (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), 0,
                                     u'Coordinated Universal Time', (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), 0))
```